Participle phrase question
I would like to ask which one (reported/reporting) should be used. It seems that "reported" has a passive meaning which doesn't make sense in the sentence. Am I correct to use "reporting"?

Air traffic control requested ad-hoc inspection following a flight (reported/reporting) an abnormal sound during takeoff from runway.


We should use reporting:

Air traffic control requested ad-hoc inspection following a flight reporting an abnormal sound ...

Here the gerund-participial clause reporting an abnormal sound means the same as the relative clause which reported an abnormal sound:

Air traffic control requested ad-hoc inspection following a flight which reported an abnormal sound ...


Shouldn't it be flight's (subject of a gerund takes the possessive case)?

you can do it either way.

after a flight reported blah blah blah

I. Present Participle or Perfect Participle.
OP's query is about choosing the correct participle for the sentence:

Air traffic control requested an ad-hoc inspection following a flight (reported/reporting) an abnormal sound during takeoff from the runway.

This sentence can be written using either the Present Participle or the Perfect Participle:

Present Participle:
Air traffic control requested an ad-hoc inspection following a flight reporting an abnormal sound during takeoff from the runway.
Perfect Participle:
A flight, having reported an abnormal sound during takeoff from the runway, prompted air traffic control to request an ad-hoc inspection.

II. Usage of Present and Perfect Participles
According to the British Council,

Present Participle clauses often function as:
Result: The bomb exploded, destroying the building..
Reason: Knowing she loved reading, Richard bought her a book..
Concurrent Action: Standing in the queue, I realised I didn't have any money..
.
Perfect Participle Clauses emphasize that the action is completed before the main clause:
Having got dressed, he slowly went downstairs..
Having finished their training, they will be fully qualified doctors..
Having been made redundant, she started looking for a new job.

III. Present or Perfect Participle?
Both "reporting" and "having reported" are grammatically correct but convey slightly different meanings:
Present Participle ("reporting"):

Suitable when the timeline is not critical.
Emphasizes the action of reporting without focusing on its completion.
Simpler and more natural in most cases.

Perfect Participle ("having reported"):

Highlights that the reporting action was completed before the inspection request.
Adds formality and clarity to the timeline.

Use "reporting" for simplicity and natural flow unless it’s essential to emphasize the timeline, in which case "having reported" is more appropriate.
